# Thickness line using pst-solides3d

Tags: pstricks, pst-solides3d

I'm trying to draw a thinness line in space using `pst-solides3d`:

```
\begin{center}
\psset{unit=0.4cm}
\psset[pst-solides3d]{viewpoint=40 30 25 rtp2xyz,Decran=60,fontsize=0}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-3)(3,10)
\psSolid[object=line,args=0 4 0 0 4 4,linewidth=0.1pt]
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
```

but command `linewidth` seems have no effect. Thanks.

Comment: `linewidth` works with `object=line`, as is demonstrated when you compile your example with something like `10pt` and `1pt`. What is your actual aim? I guess I don't understand what you mean by "thinness". If you're looking for the "thinnest line possible", then try `1sp`. However, you're still bound by the limitations of your viewer, which may/may not display it.

Comment: In fact, doing the compilation with 10pt and 1pt the thickness of the line does not suffer any change; and my purpose is change the thickness of the line. Instead, for instance, doing the same with command \axesIIID, the thickness of the axes change and works well... I don't understand.

Comment: So you don't see a difference between the width of a `10pt` and a `1pt` line in your output?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I compiled now only the code above and thickness change occurs, indeed. The point is: I have also the following in the code which seems cancel the effect of linewidth:

\defFunction[algebraic]{paraboloide1}(r,t){r*cos(t)}{2*r*sin(t)}{r^2}
\psSolid[algebraic,object=surfaceparametree,base=0 2 pi 2 div 3 pi mul 2 div ,linewidth=0.5pt,function=paraboloide1,ngrid=20 25,linecolor=blue,incolor=Turquoise]

Comment: That is a *complete* different `object`.

Comment: And what's the solution for this?

Comment: How about changing your question to contain what you're actually asking since your request has now changed? And, while you're at it, read how to construct what we call a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).